# Portability with using c++11 / recent g++ versions (4.7/4.6)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, portability, libstdc++

I've been developing an program of late using both g++ 4.6 and g++ 4.7. I'm currently taking advantage of a lot of the c++11 features.

I made this decision thinking that I would be able to just bundle the libs along with the program in a sub directory and use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I have since discovered that this is causing my program to segfault. I probably should have tested this a little earlier on huh. It appears to be the bundled libc.so.6 that is causing it (possibly others, but definitely libc).

In the past I have used this technique where it has not been possible to install libs and it has worked fine, but I have never needed to include the libc and libstdc++ along with the program.

Is there a way around this problem, or am I going to have to roll back to an older c++ / libc / libstdc++ version? (and the nightmare of code changes that comes with it)

Comment: You could always link the C++ library statically, with `-static-libstdc++`...

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. I must be using functions that require dlopen (getaddrinfo for instance), also I link against gnutls and it appears to use libs that can't be statically linked either. The  resulting binary shows libstdc++ as dynamically linked in ldd.

Comment: If the problem is libc.so.6 then it's nothing to do with gcc or g++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid relying on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- use it for testing or development but not production deployments.

Instead link with `'-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN'` to create a `DT_RPATH` tag containing `$ORIGIN` which means the dynamic linker will look for shared libs in the same dir as the executable (or e.g. use '-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib' to look in `../lib`)

If any parts of your program were built with G++ 4.7 then you need to use the libstdc++.so from GCC 4.7 at runtime.

But if the problem is in libc.so.6 it's not a GCC issue, and my advice would be do not try to bundle libc ... trying to replace the system libc probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use just g++ 4.6 or 4.7, but not both.
Also...
ldconfig will try to make your program run the /lib or /usr/lib version of libc.so, so if you have another one, I am not sure how that would work. So maybe you should just use the system libc.

If anyone else has any other ideas, post them too.